# Visual Studio 2013 ultimate with update 5 Installation issue

Tags: visual-c++

Installation of visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 5 is setting up successful but some of the features are not installing correctly. Whenever I run code I am facing a LINK ERROR. And visual studio c++ 2013 redistributable package is not installed.

[image]

Comment: Did you try do restart already?

Comment: yes i restarted